# My sets is not being updated after I do operations in a fucntion

Tags: python, function, set

I have 2 defined sets they are

```
set1 = {1, 2, 3}
set2 = {1, 3, 4, 6}
```

and I have 2 fucntions. One for add a value to sets and one for print it

```
def printSet():
    x = input("Enter name of the set\n")
    if x in globals():
        anySet = set(globals()[x])
        result = print("Your set is:\n", anySet)
    else:
        result = print("ERROR")
    return result


def addSet():
    x = input("Enter name of the set\n")
    if x in globals():
        anySet = set(globals()[x])
        print("Your set is:\n", anySet)
        y = int(input("Enter the value that you want to add to the set\n"))
        anySet.add(y)
        result = print("Your new set is:\n", anySet)
    else:
        result = print("ERROR")
    return result
```

Let's say i add the value "4" to the set1. When I print it in the fucntion the answer is

```
Your new set is:
 {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

That is okey but after the line I execute addSet fucntion, if I try to print set1 with

```
print(set1)
```

set1 is not being updated and the output is

```
 {1, 2, 3}
```

How can I fix this problem

Comment: Why you are assigning the result of `print`, which will always return `None`

Comment: In addition, I highly recommend not to create/modify variables dynamically. Use a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would work, if it weren't for the copy you are creating with `anySet = set(globals()[x])`

Simply use `anySet = globals()[x]`

Example:

```
set1 = {1, 2, 3}
def modify():
    anyset = set(globals()['set1']) # creates a copy
    anyset.add(4)
    print(set1) # {1, 2, 3}
modify()
```

W/O creating a copy:

```
set1 = {1, 2, 3}
def modify():
    anyset = globals()['set1']
    anyset.add(4)
    print(set1) # {1, 2, 3, 4}
modify()
```

Side note: using `globals()` is usually considered bad practice, maybe you could create your own global dict that references your variables by name. related issue: [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)